# Is it possible to make SVG charts in iOS?

Tags: ios, svg, charts

Is it possible to use something like SVG in native iOS applications? Or is it just a web standard?
If it's not possible, what are the other options for making vector charts in a iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

SVG is part of the HTML5 spec and Apple makes quite a marketing point about how they are standard compliant, so you should be able to display SVG in Safari.

I don't know enough about native iOS development to know if there is an SVG parsing library available.

Comment: There are SVG rendering libraries for iOS, I wrote one https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh and there's one called SVGKit too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one of the SVG rendering libraries to display SVG that you dynamically generate. I recently used [SVGgh](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh), which I wrote, in a project for a client to display some data charts. I don't know that there are any libraries to make it easier to build the actual charts, but making simple bar and pie charts are fairly easy if you are conversant with SVG.